# Problema em DUAL BOOT com Ubunt e WIndows 8.1

Tags: linux

Meu notebook (Dell Inspiron 14r 5437) já possuiu windows 8.1 instalado. Pretendo instalar o Ubuntu em dual boot, porém estou tendo o seguinte erro após dividir as partições necessárias:

> The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. 
>   This partition should be marked for use as a "Reserved BIOS boot area" and should be at least 1 MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition mounted on /boot.
>   If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct this error, boot loader installation may fail later, although it 
>   may still be possible to install the boot loader to a partition.

Segui [este tutorial](http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Dual-boot-UEFI-Ubuntu-e-Windows-8) e após a parte 6 onde clico em instalar aparece a mensagem acima, tendo a opção de continuar (com os riscos alertados) ou voltar e corrigir, porém fiquei em dúvida, pois nos tutorias que vi não aparecia esta mensagem.

Comment: A sua pergunta aparentemente é _off-topic_, para saber quais os tópicos do site consulte a página _[on-topic](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_. Sugiro que faça um _[tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)_ e consulte a [central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para saber mais sobre o site.

Comment: Seu notebook é novo provavelmente tem UEFI. Olhe este link [http://askubuntu.com/questions/458947/should-i-create-the-reserved-bios-boot-area-partition] .

Comment: Isso mesmo. Desabilita o UEFI e desative o boot em modo de segurança para que o Grub seja ativado no boot.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi meu problema ativando o secure boot novamente, e mantendo o UEFI ativado, como diz no link que o DaviAragao botou, obrigado.